# image convolutions help (image processing) without numpy

Tags: python, image-processing

I need to write function that convolving an image with a kernel.

In other words -The function receives an image with a single color channel (ie a two-dimensional list(for example - [[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]) and a kernel (also a two-dimensional list), and returns an image of the same size as the original image, with each pixel in the new image calculated by running the kernel on it.

That is: identify the pixel [image [row] [column with the main input in the kernel matrix, and sum the values ​​of its neighbors (including
The pixel itself) double the corresponding input for them in the kernel.

**When calculating a value for an x-pixel that is on the image boundaries, pixel values ​​that are outside the image boundaries should be considered.
The source seemed to have the same value as the pixel x.**

For example- for input:

image = `[[0,128,255]]`

kernel =`[[1/9 ,1/9 ,1/9],[1/9 ,1/9 ,1/9] ,[1/9 ,1/9 ,1/9]]`

output: `[[14,128,241]]`

The function starts at about zero and will place it in the center of a kernel-sized matrix, along with the adjacent values ​​that are within the boundaries of this matrix.

In the example, this is a 3 * 3 matrix and therefore the matrix we will receive after entering the values ​​is-[[0,0,0],[0,128,0],[0,0,0]].

After we have entered the corresponding values ​​we will multiply the enter matrix by the kernel matrix (respectively so that pixels in the same coordinates between the two matrices will be multiplied by each other) and sum it all together then enter the result in the image size list instead of the value 0.
And then do the same with the next value- 128 and so on.

Eventually, we will return a new image with the new pixels we calculated as I presented.

Another explanation-
https://towardsdatascience.com/types-of-convolution-kernels-simplified-f040cb307c37

According to the instructions I received I can not use a numpy.

```
def new_image(image,kernel):

    new_image= copy.deepcopy(image)

    rows = len(image)
    columns = len(image[0])
    kernel_h = len(kernel)
    kernel_w = len(kernel[0])


    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(columns):
            sum = 0
            h = (-1 * (kernel_h // 2))
            w = (-1 * (kernel_w // 2))
            for m in range(kernel_h):
                for n in range(kernel_w):

                    if 0 <= j+w < columns:
                            sum += round(kernel[m][n] * new_image[i][j+h])
                    if j + h < 0 or j + h >= columns:
                            sum += round(kernel[m][n] * new_image[i][j])
                    h+=1
                    w+=1

            new_image[i][j] = sum
    return new_image
```

This is what I wrote until now, but it does not work as required, meaning it does not return the image as required.

Output-`[[42, 131, 239]]`
instead of- `[[14,128,241]]`

Input=`[[0,128,255]`

I have no idea how to fix it, i would appreciate help.

Comment: use `print()` to see what you have in variables and compare with calculations on paper - it is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing.

Comment: Trust me ,I did  it all over the night, I just don’t know how to do it. I am siting on this for two weeks already with out significant progress.

Comment: so this is homework/a class assignment? read this to learn about the "mode": https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html what to assume for the out-of-picture values is a fundamental issue with all convolution. you could just pad the input, or you could test out-of-bounds indices in every calculation and handle the situation (use a flat color, or the nearest border pixel, ...)

Comment: Yes, it is a class homework. The problem is that I can’t use NumPy.

Comment: I don't see any `print()` in your code so I assumed you didn't try to use it to debug code. I can't test your code because you use `conv_transform()` which I don't know and you didn't add its source code. Better create minimal working code with small example data and expected result - so we could simply copy and run it to see how it works (and test some solutions)

Comment: I used `print("j:", j)` and see first problem - it is never executed - as for me you use wrong values in `ranges`, you should use `range(0, rows)` and `range(0, columns)` instead of `range(columns-w,w)` and `range(rows-h,h)`

Comment: I think some problem can also make `image.copy()` because it is shallow copy and it copies reference to internal lists (rows) instead of values from these lists - so later `new_image[i][j] = sum` may change original `image`. It may need to use `copy.deepcopy()` or you should generate new array using only width and height of original image. `new_image = [[0 for _ in range(columns)] for _ in range(rows)]`

Comment: i tried to run my code with your data and it can't give result `[[14,128,241]]` but `[[14, 42, 42]]`. And example in link uses different method - for values outside image it uses border values instead of `0` and result is `[[42, 127, 212]]`

Comment: in `conv_transform` instead of `image[len(image[0])-i-1][len(image)-j-1]` you can use `image[-i-1][-j-1]` but it has also problem with `.copy()` which make swallow copy and when you assing new value to `image_copy` then it modifies original `image`. You have to use `image_copy = copy.deepcopy(image)` or `image_copy = [row.copy() for row in image]`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I update my code, I would be thankful if you will look at it.